# Keep words together in console writeline

Tags: c#, regex, console-application, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I noticed recently that when I used Console.WriteLine on any string larger than 80 characters (or larger than the buffer size) the output would break the string exactly at 80 characters.

```
If this was really 80 characters the break wou
ld look something like that.
```

While I know I could use some regex craziness to bypass this problem, I was wondering if there was a simpler solution. I have googled it, but I can't find any code or functions for C# that keep the console from breaking up words.

Comment: You could simply come up with a method that when it reaches 80 characters, checks for the (nearest) whitespace (`" "`) and replaces it with a break (`"\r\n"`)

Comment: Side note: Optimally fit text into fixed size layout is very common interview question - there should be plenty answers (include "dynamic programming" in you search query to get better results).

Comment: Ok, that would probably help, thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586/best-word-wrap-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern (I used 40 characters in this case, change to 80)

```
^(.{1,40})\s
```

and replace with `$1\r\n`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/278)

```
# ^(.{1,40})\s
^               # Start of string/line
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  .             # Any character except line break
  {1,40}        # (repeated {1,40} times)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
\s              # <whitespace character>
```